# Downloading image in Javascript creates corrupted file

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to download an image and write it to the disk in Javascript. The image will be delivered base64 encoded by the server. I'm then trying to decode the image, create a blob with that data and create a new URL object. The download itself works, but the output file will be corrupted and unusable. My code looks as follows:

```js
jsonObject = JSON.parse(requestObject.getReturnData());
decoded = atob(jsonObject['DownloadFile']);
url = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([decoded], { type: "image/png" }));

aElement = document.createElement('a');
aElement.style.display = 'none';
aElement.href = url;
aElement.download = 'download.' + jsonObject['DownloadType'];

document.body.appendChild(aElement);
aElement.click();
window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
```

I verified that `jsonObject['DownloadFile']` contains the correct base64 representation of the image. However, it seems that there's an error when creating the blob, since its size is too big when looking at the debug console.

Comment: can you just download the image as a dataURL instead of processing it so much? You should be able to set the a.href to `"data:image/png;base64," + jsonObject['DownloadFile']`. Might also try setting location.href to the url (either data or URL-derived) to verify it's being constructed correctly.

Comment: Sometimes it can be so simple... thank you very much.